# How should I serialize Datetime into a string in AspNetUserTokens table in ASP.NET Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When I'm using OAuth2 in ASP.NET Core, the middleware converts datetimes into a string the way the result looks like

2019-05-27T13:07:49.0000000+00:00

I'm refreshing access tokens manually then and I would like to replicate this behavior. Is there any defined method to use to serialize a DateTime value into a string for subsequent writing into AspNetUserTokens table?

I know that I can use DateTime.ToString and create the formatting by analyzing 2019-05-27T13:07:49.0000000+00:00 string but I would better prefer to use something more elegant and do not depend on a particular format details. I.e. in case if tomorrow they will change something in the format, I'll use a higher-level call which will stay compatible with the changed implementation.

Actually, I see that expires_at value is already a "2019-05-27T13:07:49.0000000+00:00" string in `tokens` in googleOptions.Events.OnCreatingTicket

```
googleOptions.Events.OnCreatingTicket = ctx =>
    {
        List<AuthenticationToken> tokens = ctx.Properties.GetTokens().ToList();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
```

So this serialization is done even before putting data into database. I need to find out how they do it and use the same call (if possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That format is the [“Round-trip date/time pattern”](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Roundtrip):

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("o")); // 2019-05-27T14:34:02.8029466+02:00
```

Since this format is very verbose while being compliant with ISO 8601 and stable on all locales, it is very well suited for serializing dates and times at maximum precision.

Comment: Thank you. However, my question is different. I know that I can use DateTime.ToString but I consider it as the last resort (because it would be relying on implementation - this is what I want to avoid). I'd prefer to call some method, like, `SaveAuthenticationToken(DateTime dt)` of ASP.NET Identity API or something like that (`AuthenticationTokenSerialize(DateTime dt)`, etc). I want to leave it up to ASP.NET Core libraries to select the proper format.

Comment: OK, after some googing I found that MS itself hardcodes the format: `authProperties.UpdateTokenValue("expires_at", expiresAt.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))` at https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Security/Authentication/samples/SocialSample/Startup.cs
So, there is no high-level for it and date.ToString("o") goes as accepted answer.